# Neural Network Error Trend

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I'm relatively new to neural networks, so I was quite interested when I came across this trend in my data. I have a multilayer perceptron network using back-propagation with no momentum. The learning rate is 0.02, and the minimum margin for error allowed in training is 0.01. The network had to learn how to correctly apply an xor operation on two boolean values (their values either 1 or 0). There are biased neurons to counter the fact that the xor problem does not have linear separability (not sure if I phrased that correctly). The net's neurons are using the Sigmoid transfer function. I was wondering why the graph grows in this trend. After randomizing the network's weights again and training it again, the graph always shows up like this. Why is that?
[image: Screenshot of the error graph]

Comment: what kind of trend were you expecting?

Comment: @AndreaIacono Maybe a decreasing linear graph, or exponential decay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me that looks correct, and perhaps you're just misreading the graph. On the x-axis you have the iterations. You can consider this the time-axis for simplification. Your y-axis is the error of the network (the lower the better). So as time progresses during training your network is producing better results (with lower error).

Comment: But why is there a plateau-like shape in the middle?

Comment: There could be many reasons. The training of an ANN is almost never linear and there are a lot of so-called "flat regions" where the weights have to change by a very large value to impact a small change in the error. Many different training methods and weight update rules try to deal with this in different ways. Have you tried changing the learning rate (usually called either alpha or lambda) and see if you can get rid of the plateau?

Comment: It's hard to explain in a small comments, but you can imagine that the training algorithm is search a space (surface) of input parameters to find the lowest error. The surface for XOR is pretty well defined, but the algorithm could be starting in a diagonal direction and could be descending very little either bouncing from one side to the other of the minimum or moving too slowly. There are plenty of visualisations out in the wild that should be able to show you how gradient descent can take a long while.